# Get Name Value Pair / Exposing Dictionary to COM

Tags: c#, .net, asp-classic, com-interop

I have a class method that accepts a Dictionary object. I need to create a COM wrapper for this class. Now, I know i cant expose 'generic' anything in COM but my question is ... what collection can I use to allow the consumer to pass in the Name Value Collection to my class?

This class is going to be called from a classic ASP application and i was thinking that Classic ASP app can easily use Scripting.Dictionary and pass that as name value collection.

Would apprecaite your suggestions.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

When faced with a similar situation, I opted to save the collection to a string representation, and pass it that way.  Then de-serialize on the .NET side.  You could use JSON for the purpose.

The ASP app then submits a string, not an N/V collection. Then create a method on the .NET class that reads the string populates a Dictionary, and badda bing.

This makes sense only if it is not a high-throughput scenario, where you have hundreds of these things happening per second.  If you have 10 per second, it's probably going to work fine.

Comment: Yeah I did just that using ~ as name and value seperator and , as record seperator. Works fine, thanks!!

Comment: Still would like to know if there is a way to accomplish it without using a workaround though :)